Can I call the Seam API through Javascript in my Flutter Application?
I am building a flutter application, which has the functionality of unlocking a smart lock whenever a certain button is pressed. I am trying to use the Seam API to accomplish this. Unfortunately, Seam does not have an SDK for Dart/Flutter. Originally, I had flutter make an HTTP request to a python script I had running with flask, and though this worked it was tedious. Then I discovered flutter_js which allows me to run Javascript code from inside my flutter application. So I thought I could use the Seam Javascript SDK to make the Seam API call, but I am running into some difficulties. When I run a simple javascript function like:
function addition(n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}

It works fine.
But, when I run the javascript code which does the Seam API call, it doesn't work.
Below are the relevant code snippets:
The button press which calls the function to run Javascript:
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final result = await unlockLock(jsRuntime);
                  print(result);

                }

The function to run javascript:
Future<String> unlockLock(JavascriptRuntime jsRuntime) async {
  // Load the JavaScript code
  final blocJs = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/seam_api.js');

  // Inject the JavaScript code into the runtime

  // Evaluate the function call
  JsEvalResult jsResult = jsRuntime.evaluate("""${blocJs}unlockApartment()""");

  // Return the result
  return jsResult.stringResult;
}

The javascript code
import { Seam } from 'seam';


function unlockApartment(){

const seam = new Seam()
const lock = await seam.locks.get({ name: 'Front Door' })
await seam.locks.unlockDoor({ device_id: lock.device_id })
return 'success';

}

For this I get the error: "Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.
at undefined"
I then discovered this answer from the creator of flutter_js who said that flutter_js "allows to evaluate pure javascript code inside mobile and desktop flutter apps. By pure, I mean the package is not a browser engine, so no web API , localstorage or another browser api are available."
Does this mean that flutter_js won't work with Seam? Or is there just a bug that I am not seeing?

I’m a rookie myself but have worked through a similar issue, so I'll just drop my 2 cents in case it helps in any way.
What are you using for your mobile application's backend? In our project, we have a Flutter mobile application built on top of a .NET API. I use the C# SDK and have our API endpoint defined to open a lock, which takes the device ID as a parameter. It sounds like you might be doing something similar with Flask and a Python script. Personally, I think this is not a bad approach: setting up a Flask API and calling that from your Flutter application to perform the action. This way, the action happens server-side. If you are also getting the device ID server-side from your database, then in theory, it should be more performant. Again, I’m a rookie myself, so take all of this with a grain of salt. Community, please let me know if I’m being silly—I love to learn!
To address the issues you're facing:

Using flutter_js: The error you're seeing ("Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.") occurs because flutter_js supports only pure JavaScript and not browser-specific features like import.
Alternative Approach: Instead of running JavaScript directly in Flutter, consider setting up a backend API to handle the Seam API calls. This method offloads the complexity to the server, ensuring better security and performance.

By using this approach, you bypass the limitations of flutter_js and ensure your operations and data are securely handled on the server side. This method is more robust and scalable I believe.
Hope this helps, and I’m keen to hear what others think!

thanks for the feedback! Yeah I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't gonna waste a bunch of time with python, if there was an easier way through javascript. But yeah I will just go with python now.
